# Magento Block for in CMS pages to display links associated with that page (set in admin)

Tags: magento, widget, block

So I would like to be able to add a block to certain CMS pages, which would display links for that page.
I am thinking it will use a common (custom) template, to display the links on each page in the same manner, but I need to be able to set the links in the admin side.

I had initially thought about using a widget. which seems to make sense, and wouldn't be too hard to be able to edit in the admin side and add to a page.

But I am not sure how I could create a widget which allows for the addition of multiple links, tied to that page.

Ideally, I could add a block in the cms layout xml, perhaps check if the url path is correct, and displays the links for that page in a block.

As I write this, I realize I am not sure what the best way to accomplish this would be.

I would rather not have it be editable in the content. But I am not sure how else to make it easy to add links to a page.

Is there some way I could create a module or something where you could choose the page in the admin side, set as many links as you want (with label and URL). and then on that page, the block would load the links into the block template?

Any direction, or even a place to start would be VERY helpful. Thanks!

Comment: You can create a custom module with a custom table, custom grid, etc. Adding an item (link) would create a new row in the table. Each item would have an URL, a text and a page_id. And then edit the CMS page code to render the links associated with that page. It's the best way but you would have to be pretty advanced on Magento modules.

Comment: @SamuelComan Thank you for your reply. I continued looking into this, and came to a similar conclusion, although I am still not overly sure the best way to implement. I found this [Custom Modules With Custom Database Table](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table). But that seems like far more work than I have time for to create the desired effect. I was thinking I could make a simple Widget that offers to have 5 links, and that's all you get, and only displays the filled ones. Better thoughts?

Comment: It is the best way but for an experienced developer at least 16-20 hours are required. About using widgets, you could try. Create some sort of "standards". All the widgets starting with "links_page_" would belong to the page with that name/id. And in the template of that page, load an matching widgets and display them. I cannot think of a better solution now.

Comment: I am certainly an experienced developer, and that sounds about right for time, I just cannot commit 2 - 3 days for this solution. Perhaps in the future, but I have too many things on my plate at moment for that. I like where you're going with that idea. I will have to look into some options with that. If I come up with anything worth while I will post a response here. Of course, if anybody else has another suggestion, it would be appreciated. I need to allow someone who knows very little to add x amount of links in a block on any given cms page, specifically tied to each cms page. Thanks again